# After Sharepoint update the version is not changed

Tags: cumulative-update

I have run an update (server package 2767999 [list CU](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/26/3561010.aspx#Build)) on my SharePoint 2013 installation.

The installation ran smoothly. After the required restart 
I don't see any change.

In Central Admin/Manage servers in the farm I still see my old version.

Configuration database version: 15.0.4420.1017

instead of 15.0.4481.1005

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: You did run psconfig afterwards?

Comment: Like Robert mentions, you always need to run the configuration wizard so SharePoint can apply the update. This will pause SharePoint will installing, so make sure that you do it off-hours.

Comment: I didn't run psconfig afterwards. I'll see how to do it